# Java EventHander limitation (Time)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

My code is about the game "*Minecraft*". I want a Array item list to drop random items, what works fine.

I am trying to set up a kind of scheduler for an EventHandler.
I want the EventHandler to be executed only 5 times a minute, or every 12 seconds or something.
If I work with a "Bukkit" "runTaskLater" function, the Code is executed with a delay, but after the delay it's running permanent.

Here you have my raw code without any Scheduler.

```
@EventHandler
public void on(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();

    if(p.getLocation().getBlock().getType() == Material.STONE_PLATE) {
        if(p.getLocation().subtract(0D, 1D, 0D).getBlock().getType() == Material.STAINED_CLAY) {
                Block block = p.getLocation().getBlock();

                Random ran = new Random();
                int auswahl = ran.nextInt(2);
                        int zahl = ran.nextInt(main.Drops.size());

                        ItemStack itemstack = main.Drops.get(zahl);
                        block.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(p.getLocation(), itemstack);
                }
    }
}
```

and now this handler should be performed only every 12 seconds.

Do anyone have a solution for me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it, you want to have a cooldown. Just store the time of the last event in a variable and check if the current time is 12 seconds higher:

```
private long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
@EventHandler
public void on(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
    if (lastTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 12000) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        if(p.getLocation().getBlock().getType() == Material.STONE_PLATE) {
            if(p.getLocation().subtract(0D, 1D, 0D).getBlock().getType() == Material.STAINED_CLAY) {
                Block block = p.getLocation().getBlock();

                Random ran = new Random();
                int auswahl = ran.nextInt(2);
                int zahl = ran.nextInt(main.Drops.size());

                ItemStack itemstack = main.Drops.get(zahl);
                block.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(p.getLocation(), itemstack);
            }
        }
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

If it does not work, please comment :)